# Docker compose couldn't run static html pages

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have developed some static web-pages using jQuery & bootstrap.Here follows the folder structure,

[image]

Using below command i can able to run the docker image

Build the image

```
docker build -t weather-ui:1.0.0 .
```

Run the docker image

```
docker run -it -p 9080:80 weather-ui:1.0.0
```

Which is working fine and i can able to see the pages using http://docker-host:9080

But i would like to create a docker-compose for it,I have created a docker-compose file like below

```
version: '2'
services:
  weather-ui:
    build: .
    image: weather-ui:1.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
```

The above compose file was not working and it stuck,

```
$docker-compose up


Building weather-ui
Step 1 : FROM nginx:1.11-alpine
---> bedece1f06cc
Step 2 : MAINTAINER ***
---> Using cache
---> ef75a70d43e8
Step 3 : COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
---> 6fbc3a1d4aff
Removing intermediate container 2dc46f1f751d
Successfully built 6fbc3a1d4aff
WARNING: Image for service weather-ui was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Recreating weatherui_weather-ui_1 ...
Recreating weatherui_weather-ui_1 ... done
Attaching to weatherui_weather-ui_1
```

It stuck in the above line and i really don't know why it stuck? 
Any pointers or hint would be great to resolve this issue.

As per Antonio edit,

I can see the running container,

```
$docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
69ea4ff1a3ea        weather-ui:1.0.2    "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9080->9080/tcp   weatherui_weather-ui_1
```

But while launching the page i couldn't see anything.It says the site can't be reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose up` build your docker container (if not already done) and attach the container to your console.

If you open your browser, and go to http://localhost:9080, you should see your website.

You don't need to map a volume : `volumes: - .:/app` in docker-compose.yml because you already copy static files in Dockerfile :

```
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If you want to launch your container in the background (or in "detached" mode), add `-d` option : `docker-compose up -d`.

And by default docker-compose to not "rebuild" container if already exists, to build new container each time, add `--build` option : `docker-compose up -d --build`.

Comment: @Antonie thanks for the reply.I can see the running container but still i couldn't launch the page using http://docker-host.port ...please see the edit

Comment: As per your suggestion i have removed volume but still no luck ...it's the same

Comment: you shouldn't have build and image parameters in version '2' of docker-compose.yml file, remove image option. docker-compose here start your image `weather-ui:1.0.2` instead of build from Dockerfile (I think)

Comment: The newer version of docker-compose will support both the attribute so that shouldn't be issue ....

Comment: @Antonie could you please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: By default nginx is exposed on port 80, I think you should map port like this :  ports:   - "9080:80"

Comment: Yep it's a port issue and it is working like a charm now ....But why it is using nginx internally ? Do you have any idea ? I didn't mention nginx image in docker-compose.yml but still it is downloading the image

Comment: Eh because you referenced nginx in your Dockerfile : `FROM nginx:1.11-alpine` ^^

Comment: True...i thought docker-compose will not read dockerfile unless we referred the dockerfile into docker-compose ....

Comment: That's true, what did you reference in docker-compose.yml ? image or build ? But if you use image, and specified `weather-ui` , `weather-ui` is build from `nginx:1.11-alpine`.  Try `docker history weather-ui` to see the layer of your image